# Why some managers can be used as a class type, but the others have to be an object type

Tags: c#, swift, class, unity-game-engine, object

I've been studying both iOS app development and Unity game development, and I noticed that in swift, when you need to use a manager for example a location manager, you have to use it as an object, like:

```
let manager = CLLocationManager()
manager.requestLocation()
```

but then in Unity (uses C#), you can use the manager directly as a class type, like:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
```

What's causing the difference? is it because of the language I'm using, or the engine I'm using, or simply just because different managers have different ways to be called?

Comment: -> [the keyword `static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) ...

Answer (score 1):

Static classes do not require an instance, so methods can be called directly. Check from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) : A static class is basically the same as a non-static class, but there is one difference: a static class cannot be instantiated. In other words, you cannot use the new operator to create a variable of the class type. Because there is no instance variable, you access the members of a static class by using the class name itself.

For the case of the `SceneManager` its not a `static` class, but a static method. You can read about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) if yopu wish.

In c# and Javascript, many times you need an instance to access a method of a determined type/object. Which seems to be the case of the `CLLocationManager()`, which I am not familiar with.

To Sum up, the methods you call in the `SceneManager` are static, and the `requestLocation` of the `CLLocationManager` presumably not, so you need to get an instance for the call.

In javascript, apart from the [static](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) keyword itself, you can use this trick to use Javascript object methods to be called directly, which is kind of to use an object as a namespace.

```
var nameSpaceName= {

    foo: function() {
    },

    bar: function() {
    }
};

nameSpaceName.foo();
```

Aestheatically it removes the need of an instance in the code so that the methods within can be called directly, but of course the concept of being `Static` is totally different. I mention this because your question focuses more in how the method is called, than in the concept behind, so though it was worth mentioning the namespace/static similar way to call things, even the technical concept and purpose are so different.

Comment: Thank you for your reply that helped a lot! actually CLLocationManager() is a Swift class for finding the location of an iOS device.

Comment: @Dr.42 No it's not. `CLLocationManager` is a Swift class. `CLLocationManager()` is the invocation of the initializer (constructor) on that class, which results in an *object*, not a class.

Answer (score 0):

A manager isn’t a “thing” as far as any of these systems are concerned. It’s just a name for human purposes.

These are just different APIs with different designs. There’s nothing more to it.

One expects you to instantiate it and call instance methods methods on its new instance, the other expects you to call class methods directly on the class.